# Total number of DML and DDL operations performed in a table in oracle

Tags: oracle

I would like to know the total number of operations (DDL and DDL) performed on a table in oracle dabatase since it was created.

Is there a query for it?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10118/120

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your database has been running in `ARCHIVELOG` mode and supplemental logging is enabled, you can historically mine the archive logs using [Log Miner](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm).

There's a nice demo [on this page](http://oracleflash.com/24/How-to-read-or-analyze-redo-log-files-using-LogMiner.html).

May I ask why you want the total number of operations? The numbers by themselves are meaningless.

Comment: Yes, we are running it in archivelog. I am developing an application that will retrieve this number each day and save it, so we have an statistic of db use.

Comment: I think you'd be better off defining other metrics, as these don't really mean much. Things like "Table growth in rows/blocks/extents"

Comment: Yes, that's what we want, but couldn't table growth in rows be (rows after - rows before)?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no simple query for this, if you did not setup auditing for this.

You could use auditing to track ddl that changes tables.
You could create a procedure that tracks the # of rows affected by dml operations by reading dba_tab_modifications, before the table is analyzed, and store that in an own table to keep a historical view on it. Not for the # of dml.
If you have ASH available you could also find out the # of dml on a table and record those statistics in own tables. ASH tends to grow a lot so there is a purging policy on it.

So, the simple answer is no but as is the case with many things in Oracle database, with a little creative thinking, it can be made available.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you are really interested in knowing the growth of the object over time.  You could create a table to store this data and as frequently as you want to see changes, insert into the table the results of the this query:

```
SELECT owner, segment_name, sum(blocks) BlockCount, sysdate GatherDate
FROM dba_extents WHERE segment_name='**Your Table Name Here***' GROUP BY owner, segment_name;
```

You could then create queries to show differences between different time periods or even graph the results.

Answer (score 0):

SQL> execute dbms_stats.flush_database_monitoring_info;

SQL> select table_owner,table_name,inserts,updates,deletes from dba_tab_modifications ;